# Phonegap plugin half-screen camera ala Taptalk

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins, ios-camera

I am trying to mimic the half-screen camera as exists in apps like [Taptalk](https://www.taptalk.me/). The goal is to have a live camera in a self-contained view on the upper half of the screen controlled by a Cordova plugin, with the lower half of the screen containing the normal HTML-based Cordova content.

I know the standard cordova camera plugin allows you to bring up the fullscreen camera component, and I know that doing this natively, at least on iOS would be relatively straightforward, but I'm really not sure where I would start trying to do this in a cross-platform way within a larger phonegap app (via Ionic).

I'm guessing I need to write a custom Cordova plugin ala this excellent [article](http://codrspace.com/vote539/writing-a-custom-camera-plugin-for-phonegap/), but the main conceptual issue I'm worried about is that I think I'd have to use a view positioned and sized to only fill the top half of the screen, as opposed to a fullscreen ViewController (focusing on iOS for now).

Does anyone have any advice for implementing this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own Cordova plugin, [SnapsCamera](https://github.com/SnapsApp/snaps_camera).

It uses a half-screen-sized view with UIImagePickerController's UIView added as a subview.